# Cannot Find Symbol @Generated Using Dagger 2 and Proguard in Library Module

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, proguard, dagger-2

I had to have my laptop imaged at work. Now the project won't build. Other developers can continue building at the same commit fine so it must be an environment issue somewhere.

I use Dagger 2 in my fully Kotlin project that has an `app` module and then have a separate `data` module. When compiling a *release* build with proguard enabled I get the following error in all of the generated classes of the `data` library module (it may happen in the `app` module too but its not getting that far):

```
error: cannot find symbol
@Generated(
 ^
  symbol: class Generated
100 errors


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':data:compileProductionReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

My `data` module's `build.gradle` file has this in it for dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Which is the same as my `app` module's

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Both files have the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at the top of them.

I have tried clean building, invalidating the caches and restarting Android Studio but have had no luck. I also tried adding the additional `kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1'` to the `data` module but that also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my laptop being wiped and the only version of Java being installed was `1.10`, the installation of gradle was using that version of the JDK. (`gradle -v` shows this version.

To rectify this I used homebrew to download Java 8.

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

And then so that gradle used version 1.8 I put the following lines in my `/etc/profile` file.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I then ran `source /etc/profile` and voila. My project can be built again!